# How to debug hard drive power saving?

Tags: hard-disk, power-management, hdparm

My harddrives are not going to powersave.

I have added the following lines into `/etc/hdparm.conf`:

```
command_line {
    hdparm -S 25 /dev/disk/by-uuid/42d40d37-2859-457c-93d0-e4c617d06d9f
}

command_line {
    hdparm -S 25 /dev/disk/by-uuid/e7274b44-09e1-4a3c-90e7-01327f8ed8d4
}

command_line {
    hdparm -S 25 /dev/disk/by-uuid/71223a72-6e5b-4075-9170-1e5f0217798c
}
```

but they apparently have no effect.

```
$ sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 drive state is:  active/idle
```

all the time.

How to know if it is configuration problem or some disk activity wakens the drive? If it is disk activity, then how to know if it is it and which it was?

My OS is `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`.

Comment: What does `hdparm -B /dev/sdc` say?  If your `APM_level` is greater than 127, see the meaning of `-B` in `man hdparm`.

Comment: It says `APM_level      = not supported`

Comment: @goldilocks, APM is obsolete junk from the days before ACPI.

Answer (score 2):

Known bug in udisks.  Upgrading to 15.04 will fix it: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1281588

Comment: Is it affects if I don't use Gnome or GUI?

Comment: @Dims, hrm.. if you don't ever log into the gui, then no, I don't think udisks runs.  Run `ps aux` and see if udisksd is running.

Comment: I probably did logged into GUI, but i'd better kill it than upgrade from LTS to non-LTS.

Comment: `udisksd` is not running and not installed on my system

Comment: @Dims, then you have something else that keeps touching the disks.  You might use `blktrace` to find out what.